# How to remove /index from the homepage URL extension of my site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

How would you remove the index extension from the home page URL of your site? When I go to my site the URL shows as www.example.com/ then later if i click on the about page for example and click the logo which I have a href on it then directs back to the home page and then shows www.example.com/index - is there a way to simply remove this from the index page only as it just doesn't look that great.

I'm using a Perch provided .htaccess file ifModule to remove the .php file extensions if this helps:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to PHP if it exists.
# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

performs an internal re-write of the requested URL only. That means any changes to the URL resulting from the rewrite are NOT visible to the client.

That means if your HTML contains the normal "php is visible" links, that's what the user will see in their address bad. As such, all of your client-side links MUST be in the re-written no-php versions

```
<a href="/">..</a> This is ok - no php visible, user see http://example.com/
<a href="/index">..</a> Also ok: http://example.com/index
<a href="/index.php">..</a> Nope: user sees http://example.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to change the link on your logo from `index.php` to `/`, which is the root of your website...

```
<a href="/index">...</a> 
... becomes ...
<a href="/">...</a>
```

Otherwise, you can add an Apache RewriteRule that match `/index` and redirect to `/`, with a `301`HTTP code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why do you need 301? Can't you just rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

This is the rule you can place as **your first rule** to hide/remove index.php from anywhere:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```